# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'numpy.ndarray' and 'numpy.ndarray'

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn

I am trying to calculate the Mean Squared Error of the predictions `y_train_actual` from my sci-kit learn model with the original values `salaries`.

**Problem:** However with `mean_squared_error(y_train_actual, salaries)`, I am getting the error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'numpy.ndarray' and 'numpy.ndarray'`. Using `list(salaries)` instead of `salaries` as the 2nd parameter gives the same error.

With `mean_squared_error(y_train_actual, y_valid_actual)` I am getting the error `Found array with dim 40663. Expected 244768`

How can I convert to the correct array types for `sklearn.netrucs.mean_squared_error()`?

**Code**

```
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

y_train_actual = [ np.exp(float(row)) for row in y_train ]
print mean_squared_error(y_train_actual, salaries)
```

**Error**

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-144-b6d4557ba9c5> in <module>()
      3 y_valid_actual = [ np.exp(float(row)) for row in y_valid ]
      4 
----> 5 print mean_squared_error(y_train_actual, salaries)
      6 print mean_squared_error(y_train_actual, y_valid_actual)

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\metrics.pyc in mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred)
   1462     """
   1463     y_true, y_pred = check_arrays(y_true, y_pred)
-> 1464     return np.mean((y_pred - y_true) ** 2)
   1465 
   1466 

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'numpy.ndarray' and 'numpy.ndarray'
```

**Code**

```
y_train_actual = [ np.exp(float(row)) for row in y_train ]
y_valid_actual = [ np.exp(float(row)) for row in y_valid ]

print mean_squared_error(y_train_actual, y_valid_actual)
```

**Error**

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-146-7fcd0367c6f1> in <module>()
      4 
      5 #print mean_squared_error(y_train_actual, salaries)
----> 6 print mean_squared_error(y_train_actual, y_valid_actual)

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\metrics.pyc in mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred)
   1461 
   1462     """
-> 1463     y_true, y_pred = check_arrays(y_true, y_pred)
   1464     return np.mean((y_pred - y_true) ** 2)
   1465 

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.pyc in check_arrays(*arrays, **options)
    191         if size != n_samples:
    192             raise ValueError("Found array with dim %d. Expected %d"
--> 193                              % (size, n_samples))
    194 
    195         if not allow_lists or hasattr(array, "shape"):

ValueError: Found array with dim 40663. Expected 244768
```

**Code**

```
print type(y_train)
print type(y_train_actual)
print type(salaries)
```

**Result**

```
<type 'list'>
<type 'list'>
<type 'tuple'>
```

---

**print y_train[:10]**

`[10.126631103850338, 10.308952660644293, 10.308952660644293, 10.221941283654663, 10.126631103850338, 10.126631103850338, 11.225243392518447, 9.9987977323404529, 10.043249494911286, 11.350406535472453]`

**print salaries[:10]**

`('25000', '30000', '30000', '27500', '25000', '25000', '75000', '22000', '23000', '85000')`

**print list(salaries)[:10]**

`['25000', '30000', '30000', '27500', '25000', '25000', '75000', '22000', '23000', '85000']`

**print len(y_train)**

```
244768
```

**print len(salaries)**

```
244768
```

Comment: Can you add the `shape` of y_train? My guess is that y_train_actual is a `list` of `ndarrays`, which might end up in a conflict within `mean_square_error()`.

Comment: @fgb I get the error `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'`

Comment: True that. Do you have an idea of the dimensions of y_train?

Comment: @fgb `len(y_train)` gives `244768`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `TypeError` problem stems from salaries being a list of strings while y_train_actual is a list of floats. Those cannot be subtracted.

For your second error, you should make sure that both arrays are of the same size, otherwise it cannot subtract them.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and get the error `float() argument must be a string or a number`

Comment: Did you use `np.float()`, which acts on `numpy.ndarrays`?

Comment: yup I did use `np.float()` instead of `float()`

Comment: See my fix in the answer above. You actually need to cast the list as an `np.array()` with `np.float` as its `dtype`.

Comment: Tried that and got the error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'numpy.ndarray' and 'numpy.ndarray'`

Comment: Ok, so no dice. Time to regroup.

Comment: I'm making a wild guess that `mean_squared_error()` will not take in an array created by numpy

Comment: Maybe. You added that the array dimension is unexpected `mean_squared_error(y_train_actual, y_valid_actual)`. Could it be that the two lists are not the same length? That will make a subtraction throw an error.

Comment: For `mean_squared_error(y_train_actual, y_valid_actual)`, yes you are right, both lists are not the same length so they cause the error. For the first error involving `mean_squared_error(y_train_actual, salaries)` its giving an error complaining about the ndarray

Comment: What version of `numpy` are you running? You can get it through `pip freeze` or the like.

Comment: I got rid of the first error by using `salaries
 = [ float(salary) for salary in salaries ]` to convert the strings in the list `salaries` into floats. `print np.__version__` gives `1.7.1`

Comment: Yeah, subtracting strings and floats was going to be hard. ;)

Comment: :) For the second error, will you simply truncate the list `y_train_actual[:40663]` and still get a meaningful mean squared error? I'm getting an MSE of 500 million so I guess its the wrong way.

Comment: That's much harder to know. Can you explain what y_train and y_valid, and their actual counterparts, represent?

Comment: I have some job advertisement text vectorized as `X_train` and their respective salaries as `y_train`. These are used to fit a linear regression model `rr = Ridge().fit(X_train, y_train)`. This model `rr` is then used to predict the salaries of a "validation" test set of job ads vectorized as `X_valid`. Its predictions `y_valid` is calculated using `y_valid = rr.predict(X_valid)`. I want a way to evaluate the performance of the regression model and tried MSE. Is there a better way?

Comment: Yeah, to compare two signals via a `mean_square_error()` measure they need to be of the same dimensions. Otherwise, you'll have to manually compare the shorter signal to different portions of the longer one so as to find the portion with the least MSE, assuming that's your goal.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29282/discussion-between-fgb-and-nyxynyx)

Comment: Interesting approach to your job search. You're trying to compare the predicted y_valid values to the actual ones from the test set's ground truth? I'm a bit confused with the variable names. Is y_train_actual your predictions while y_valid_actual the real values you're using for the MSE or viceversa?